# Having trouble in ML prediction algorithm

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, classification

I am learning ML and was working on making a single layer neural network. The learning part is going perfectly. Unfortunately, I can't understand how I can use the resulting weight `syn0` to predict the answer to the test cases in `x_test`.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

def nonlinear(x, deriv = False):
    if(deriv==True):
        return x*(1-x)

    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

def predict(x_test, y_test, ss):
    prediction = nonlinear(np.abs(np.dot(x_test,ss)))
    error = np.mean(np.abs(y_test - prediction))
    print("P:",prediction,"\nE:",error)

x = np.array([[1,0,1],
              [0,1,1],
              [0,1,0],
              [1,1,1]])

y = np.array([[1],
              [0],
              [0],
              [0]])

x_test = np.array([[1,0,0],
                   [1,0,1],
                   [0,1,1],
                   [0,1,0]])

y_test = np.array([[1],
                   [1],
                   [0],
                   [0]])

np.random.seed(1)

syn0 = 2*np.random.random((3,1)) - 1 

for _ in range(100000):

    l0 = x
    l1 = nonlinear(np.dot(l0, syn0))

    l1_error = y - l1

    if (_%10000) == 0:
        print("Error at Gen",_,":", str(np.mean(np.abs(l1_error))))
        print(l1)

    l1_delta = l1_error * nonlinear(l1, deriv = True)

    syn0 += l0.T.dot(l1_delta)

print(syn0)

predict(x_test, y_test, syn0)
```

Comment: What do you mean? it is already happening on the last line where you are calling `predict(x_test, y_test, syn0)`. That function prints out your predictions and your errors for `x_test`

Comment: But the prediction is way off and the error is ALWAYS almost 0.5 on a scale of one and all of the predictions are almost 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your prediction function, I do not see a reason why we should include an absolute value, that is not part of the softmax function AFAIK. I changed it as follows:

```
def predict(x_test, y_test, ss):
    prediction = nonlinear(np.dot(x_test,ss))
    error = np.mean(np.abs(y_test - prediction))
    print("P:",prediction,"\nE:",error)
```

This fixed the problem and I received perfect prediction. [0.9, 0.9, 0.0, 0.0]. One think you need to be aware of, is that your response variables are labels, namely, 0 and 1. While your model returns probabilities. Although your heuristic for the error is fine, personally I would prefer to have a cut off to see how my classifier is performing. I.e. I would say after the prediction is done, anything with a probability more than 0.5 is label 1 and anything with a probability less than 0.5 is label zero.

That will give a better measure of the accuracy of the model IMO, however I can see the merit of using an continuous error measure, that will work really good when your labels are well separated and the classifier is confident.

I think your problem was more with the math and less with the implementation, If you want to know more about neural networks, I suggest [this](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/) website